# How to append MySQL array data to premade JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm having trouble appending data returned from a MySQL table into a PHP JSON object.
This is the premade object, and it works fine on its own. What I'd like to do is append extra data to this object.

```
$profileData = '{
    "uid": "'.$uid['id'].'",
    "username": "'.$user.'",
    "cover": "'.$userData['profile_cov'].'",
    "propic": "'.$userData['profile_pic'].'",
    "fullName": "'.$userData['full_name'].'",
    "about": "'.$userData['about'].'",
    "relationship": "'.$userData['relationship'].'",
    "location": "'.$userData['location'].'",
    "work": "'.$userData['work'].'",
    "sexPref": "'.$userData['sex_pref'].'",
    "edu": "'.$userData['education'].'",
    "hometown": "'.$userData['hometown'].'",
    "isFollowing": "'.$isFollowingResult.'",
    "areFriends": "'.$areFriendsResult.'"
}';
```

This is the data I'd like to append to the above object. How can I do this?

```
$getPosts = "SELECT `author`, `access`, `post`, `posted` FROM `posts` WHERE `author` =   '$userData[username]' AND `access` = 'Public' ORDER BY `posted` DESC";
$postResults = $cnct->query($getPosts);
$rows = array();
while($usrPosts = $postResults->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $usrPosts;
}
$data = array('Posts' => $rows);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Query JSON Output example:

```
{"Posts":[{"author":"Elitis","access":"Public","post":"Test 4","posted":"2014-06-20 14:02:09"}]}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you get from that database query/JSON output? If the data structures are the same, you should just be able to `array_merge()` to two arrays together then encode that. If they aren't the same data structure, you need to make them the same, then follow step one above.

Comment: Updated OP. That what you were looking for? @scrowler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not** create JSON manually , it is very poor approach and your code **will** break one day

```
$profileData = array(
    'uid'=> $uid['id'],
    'username'=>$user,
    'cover'=>$userData['profile_cov'],
    'propic'=>$userData['profile_pic'],
    'fullName'=> $userData['full_name'],
    'about'=> $userData['about'],
    'relationship'=> $userData['relationship'],
    'location'=> $userData['location'],
    'work'=> $userData['work'],
    'sexPref'=> $userData['sex_pref'],
    'edu'=> $userData['education'],
    'hometown'=> $userData['hometown'],
    'isFollowing'=> $isFollowingResult,
    'areFriends'=> $areFriendsResult
);
```

Then it is very easy to append data:

```
profileData['Posts'] = $rows;
echo json_encode($profileData);
```

Comment: What, specifically, makes creating JSON manually bad practice? Also, using this approach, how would I access the posts client-side? x.Posts.post?

Comment: @Azrael it is bad practice because PHP has an inbuilt function to handle it for you, and while that function will be kept as up to date with current standards, bug fixes, issues etc at all times, your custom functions will not be (because you won't want to!). Best to rely on `json_encode()` here